# KML complex schema

Tags: kml

I'm new to Kml and i'm searching for a way to define a more complex kml schema that can contain: a defined region, and inside the region all the countries of the region with their coordinates. So the schema has to contain a complex element and not a simple one.

Currently i have this structure for country. But i don't know how can i make one for region.

```
<Schema parent="Placemark" name="S_country">  
    <SimpleField type="wstring" name="CNTRY_NAME">
    </SimpleField> 
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="wstring" name="CURR_TYPE">
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="wstring" name="CURR_CODE">
    </SimpleField>
  </Schema>
```

It is possible to have complex elements inside the schema?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this. It's the least thing you can do other than doing your own research.

[Advance KML 1: Easy Note](http://ge.images.alaska.edu/workshop/advanced.htm)
[Advance KML 2: Google Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html)